# Visual Studio 2013 Flexera customer community tab

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installshield

First of all, they took away the default setup project and give us a 3rd party tool to package ( maybe its a topic for a separate forum),  but visual studio keeps opening a new tab with the flexera customer support page(with an irritating javascript error) whenever i have a 'error' in my code .

how can i disable this feature ?

Comment: I'd also love to get rid of this.  We currently have 8 different setup projects in one solution. Building the solution causes 8 of these popups and javascript error dialogs.

Comment: So far, the only way I've found to avoid this is to fix the error. Not much of a "fix" though but it sure is annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a workaround, you can go to Solution Properties -> Configuration Properties -> and uncheck the Build action for the setup Project (then close and reopen visual studio).

Later you reactivate it only when setup creation is required.

Comment: This is not a solution/answer, and the workaround is only useful for some users. I NEED my setup projects to build; I can't disable them in configuration properties or unload them. When I rebuild the solution, the rebuild SUCCEEDS, but this window pops up 7 times, and each time has a JavaScript error. I understand that there may not BE a solution (Flexera may not allow you to disable this tab), but that doesn't make this answer any more valid.

Comment: I've stated cleary that is a workaround. If the inquirer considered it as a valid answer is his choice, not my problem.

Comment: Workaround or not, I found this helpful. To make it a little more manageable, I have one solution configuration that builds the setup project, while the rest do not. I only switch to that configuration when I need setup to build. That way, I don't have to reactivate it in the build configurations.

Comment: I also found that, even with this project removed from the build actions, it can be manually built by right-clicking it & choosing build. Not great, but is much more preferable than having the browser tab constantly popping up inside VS.

Answer (score 5):

Another workaround. 
Right-click on setup project and choose Unload Project.
When you want to build setup again, use Reload Project.

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution, but another workaround.  Edit your hosts file and point that website to localhost.  Gets rid of the popups, but not the extra tab in Visual Studio.

1) Run this:

```
notepad C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

2) Add this text and save the file:

```
# To get rid of the annoying javascript error popups in Visual Studio
# Example problem URL: http://flexerasoftware.force.com/SupportKBList?searchString=-1014
127.0.0.1   flexerasoftware.force.com
```

3) Run this:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

4) Close re-open Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite workaround (10 seconds but must be re-done after each VS2013 restart):

1) Right click the tab and click [Float]

2) Minimize the window and put it in an unused corner of VS 2013